# Neo4j: How to find all nodes that: connected to either 0 nodes with specific property, or all nodes with property set

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have a directed graph with nodes of types A and B. Nodes of type A can be connected to nodes of type A or B, and nodes of type B have no outgoing connections.

Also, nodes B has a `boolean` property. I need to find all nodes A that:
have no direct or inderect connections to nodes B
if node A has conection to at least 1 node B, it should be returned only if all connected nodes B has a property set to true.

Or in other words, I need to find all A which are not connected to any B with property set to false.

I was trying to do it with query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:A)-[*]->(b:B)
WITH a,b, collect(b) as bc
WITH a,b,COLLECT(bc) AS coll
UNWIND coll as unwinded
WITH a,b,unwinded
WHERE ALL (x IN unwinded WHERE x.prop = true)
return a
```

But it returns me A if they have at least 1 b with `prop=true`. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should return all `A` nodes that have no connected `B` nodes with a false `prop`:

```
MATCH (a:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[*]->(b:B { prop: false })
WITH a, COLLECT(b) AS bs
WHERE SIZE(bs)= 0
RETURN a;
```

Here is [a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=5qc1p0) showing this query.

[UPDATE]

As suggested by @InverseFalcon, the above query can be greatly simplified:

```
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE NOT (a)-[*]->(:B {prop:false})
RETURN a;
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm wondering what is wrong with my query. Looks like I don't fully understand how WHERE ALL () works

Comment: Note that it should be possible to shorten this a bit: `MATCH (a:A) WHERE NOT (a)-[*]->(:B {prop:false}) RETURN a`

Comment: @InverseFalcon Another great suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
MATCH (a:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[*]->(b:B {prop: false})
WITH a, b
WHERE b IS NULL
RETURN a
```

Comment: This query returns all `A` nodes. The `WHERE` clause only filters the second `(OPTIONAL) MATCH`, and does not eliminate any of the `A` nodes found by the first match.

Comment: Thanks again, cyphersam! ;)  I think that the `WITH` that I just added should fix it

Comment: This is a subtle solution, and possibly more efficient than mine. Pretty neat.